# For and while loop not removing items from list

Tags: python, list, loops

Imagine I have a list L that has the following items:

```
L = [1,1,2,3]
```

Let's say that I want to remove each item but also count the amount of "ones", "twos" and "threes" that are on the list. So we define the following variables

```
ones = 0
twos = 0
threes = 0
```

One way I tried to solve this problem was by using a for loop and a while loop in the following way:

```
for item in L:
    while item in L:
        if item == 1:
            ones += 1
            L.remove(item)
        elif item == 2:
            twos += 1
            L.remove(item)
        elif item == 3:
            threes += 1
            L.remove(item)
```

But for whatever reason, the list L remains as

```
L = [2]
```

and the variables

```
ones = 2
twos = 0
threes = 1
```

Can someone explain why is it not removing and counting the 2 and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I am aware of a way of counting items on a list (count method for example) but I would still like to know why this is happening

Comment: Try iterating list indices instead of iterating the list itself.

Comment: "Let's say that I want to remove each item" So just do all the counting first, and then empty the list afterwards? Why make it complicated?

Comment: You're right. I shouldn't have made it complicated. I just stumbled upon it and wanted to know why it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop considers the value at each index in `L`.

The first iteration of the `for` considers value at index 0.

The second iteration of the `for` considers value at index 1.

Since you modify the list in-situ, by the time index 1 is considered, the value there is `3`.

The value `2` isn't considered because that moves to index 0, which has already been considered at that point in time.

To help illustrate this, I've used the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to expose both index and value in your `for` loop:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

L = [1,1,2,3]

ones = 0
twos = 0
threes = 0

for index, item in enumerate(L):
    print(f"Consider value at index {index} in {L} (value: {item})")
    while item in L:
        if item == 1:
            ones += 1
            L.remove(item)
        elif item == 2:
            twos += 1
            L.remove(item)
        elif item == 3:
            threes += 1
            L.remove(item)

# Consider value at index 0 in [1, 1, 2, 3] (value: 1)
# Consider value at index 1 in [2, 3] (value: 3)
```

You can fix this by iterating over a copy of the list in your `for`.

One way of making a copy of it is to append an empty list, making a new list that's the same.

To do this, change your `for` to be:

```py
for item in L+[]:
```

Alternatively, you can create a more concise solution by using [list.count](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) in a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

L = [1,1,2,3]
counts = { i:L.count(i) for i in set(L) }
print(counts)
```

Comment: Much clearer. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you start iterating over the list of numbers, you shouldn't be altering the list itself, an idea may be to copy the values to a second list and use it as support for the loop

```
a = [1,1,2,3]
b = a.copy()
count = {}

for i in b:
    print(i)
    if i in count:
        count[i] += 1
    else:
        count[i] = 1
    a.remove(i)
print(count)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will pay attention to not altering the list when iterating over it.